# How to fix SQL injection with preparedstatment?

Tags: java, prepared-statement

I have a class that is being flagged by a veracode scan for SQL injection, even though I am using a PreparedStatment.  I cann't determine where the issue lies, or if this is a possible false positive from the scan.  Please refer to the code below (QueryBuffer is a custom class that uses a StringBuffer):

```
List<ReferralService> list = new ArrayList<ReferralService>();
QueryBuffer sql = new QueryBuffer();
sql.addSql("SELECT rs.id FROM referral_service rs ");
sql.addSql("WHERE ");
sql.addSql("rs.closed = ? AND ");
sql.addSql("rs.workflow_id = ? ");
sql.addSql("ORDER BY submitted_on ASC limit 200");

PreparedStatement prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
prepStmt.setInt(1, 0);
prepStmt.setInt(2, liTeamID);
ResultSet rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Looks like a false positive. You can probably get rid of it by not using that QueryBuffer, but instead just directly prepare the statement from a single String literal.

Comment: Why are you even using that `QueryBuffer`? In the code shown it just adds unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like veracode is not happy with the string concatenation.

It is more an SQL injection that might happen in the future when (another) developer will extend the code and add bad things to the string (like variables).

So please avoid using all these addSql strings.